# How to merge excel files that are in io.BytesIO() object?

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint

I am working in Python with office-365 sharepoint-api and have been downloading, uploading, and modifying Excel files. Now I want to grab two files from sharepoint and combine them but I cannot find a way to do it. What is the simplest way to combine the sheets of the two files?

Here's my code for modifying Excel files:

```
def modify_excel_file_contents(self file_name, df_list, sheetnames, loc, folder_path='', df_index__=False):
    conn = self._auth()
    folder_path = _correct_folder_path(folder_path)
    file_url = f'/sites/{self.site_name}/{DOC_LIBRARY}{folder_path}/{file_name}'
    excel_doc = File.open_binary(conn, file_url)
    bytes fie obj = io.BytesIO()
    bytes_fie_obj.write(excel_doc.content)
    bytes_fie_obj.seek(0)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(bytes_fie_obj, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        for df, sheetname in zip(df_list, sheetnames):
            df.to_excel (writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=df_index, startrow=loc[0], startcol=loc[1])
    return bytes_fie_obj.getvalue()
```

Here is my function for appending data from `DataFrames` onto an Excel file but I am trying to make another function that will combine sheets from two Excel files and then append them with DataFrame. I cannot combine them as BytesIO objects and loading them as a workbook has not solved the problem either.

Comment: your function for appending data from DataFrames is missing in your question

Comment: I am using openpyxl to overlay data on the sheets and the to_excel function is part of the pandas library.